# BLE Sleep and Rx Mode

Tags: power, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, receiver, sleep

A Generic Tx Node:
Cycle time - 5s.
Tx Time (wake up, Tx, Sleep back)  - 0.1ms -> current consumption 30mA.
Actual Sleep Time (some sleep mode)- 4.9ms -> current consumption 20uA.

However for a Rx Node, which should do a task only if the right message was received.
Can i put it in some sleep mode which takes uA range current and still get some interrupt when a BLE message with the intended access address is present.

Something like
cycle time - NA (as this will do something only is there is rx message)
Sleep time  - NA -> current consumption 20uA.
Active time - 0.1ms -> current consumption 30mA.

Can we do something like this using BLE.
This is the product i plan to use , https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52820_PS_v1.3.pdf

can i use a sleep mode like this,

[image]

and be able to detect if a message has been transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

No, the BLE radio in what you've called the "Rx Node" can *not* receive a message and "wake up" the system when the IC is in sleep mode.

Let's redesignate the Tx node as the *Peripheral*, and the Rx Node as the *Central* (because truth be told, they both do some transmitting and receiving in the BLE protocol).

To begin, have the Peripheral *advertise* and the Central *scan*. Once the Central confirms it's the desired device, they should establish a *connection*. They will each then periodically turn on at agreed-upon intervals to exchange information, sleeping in between.

To conserve energy, set the connection interval to be long (e.g. your 5 second spec).  You can even configure the connection so the peripheral can  skip some connection intervals if it has no new data.

Study and try out the examples in the software development kit for the BLE IC. You'll find the SDK includes firmware that controls the radio in the manner described.

Comment: Thank you for this - " Rx Node can not receive a message and "wake up" the system when the IC is in sleep mode" 


I am aware that the Tx and Rx nodes will both transmit and receive.


I did not consider this - "They will each then periodically turn on at agreed-upon intervals to exchange information". However what if the connection is dropped due to some physical obstacle for some 20-30 mins then will the devices stay awake until they find each other ?

Comment: I will be studying the SOC, once i make sure that BLE can be used for my scenario.

Comment: If the connection is dropped, the Peripheral will return to advertising, and the Central will return to scanning, until they can re-establish the connection. The devices sleep between advertisements and scans to conserve power, but power consumption will still be somewhat higher than when connected. Use long advertising and scanning intervals to reduce consumption if you can withstand a delay in reconnecting.